# How to access variables in the function where apply_filters() is called?

Tags: hooks, filters

I am trying to filter some data based on whether a variable from within the function that calls `apply_filters()` is equal to specific value. That variable is not passed to the `apply_filters()` parameters. This might explain what I mean:

```
// function in wordpress core
function get_var_b() {
    // generating $var_a
    $var_a = "a";
    // some code ...
    $var_b = apply_filters('get_var_b', $var_b);
    return $bar_b;
}

// in functions.php
add_filter('get_var_b', 'filter_var_b');
function filter_var_b($var_b) {
    if ($var_a == "c") {
        $var_b = "d";
    }
    return $var_b;
}
```

I tried to use `global $var_a;` inside of my function but with no success. The only way I could access `$var_a` was by editing the core file and passing `$var_a` to the `apply_filters()` function like:

```
apply_filters('get_var_b', $var_b, $var_a);
```

Is there a way to access this variable without editing the core file or trying to regenerate $var_a from scratch? Thanks.

**EDIT:** The filter that I am trying to hook to is `dynamic_sidebar_params` which is called from `dynamic_sidebar()` function in `wp-includes/widgets.php` file. I am trying to change the `$params[0]['before_widget']` from `<aside>` to `<nav>` IF the `$id` was equal to `categories-2`.

Comment: It would be much easier if you're telling us the actual core function name.

Comment: I have updated the question and add my actual case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **you can't.**

You're trying to access a variable outside of its scope.  In your situation, `$var_a` is *local* to the `get_var_b()` function, so anything outside of that function cannot see it.

This is equivalent to writing this sequence in PHP:

```
function get_var_b() {
    // This variable is local to the function and invisible outside of it.
    $var_a = "a";  

    // Call a function that returns some value while passing in some default value.
    $var_b = create_var_b( 'default' ); 

    return $var_b;
}

function create_var_b( $default = null ) {
    // Inside this function, we only have access to $default because that's all that was passed
    // in. You can access any set global variables my making an explicit reference to 
    // "global $var", but only if the variable was globalized in its original scope.

    if ($default != null) {
        $var_b = "d";
    } else {
        $var_b = "c";
    }

    return $var_b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I thought that my function `filter_var_b()` will be called from within the core function `get_var_b()` and hence will have access to its local variables.

Comment: Yes and no. The `apply_filters()` function uses `call_user_func_array()` to invoke your registered function, pass in the values specified, and return the filtered value *within your function*.  But just because it's invoked from within your function doesn't mean it will have access to your function's scope. It can only see what's in the global scope or what you've explicitly passed in.